# SMS is stuck as "not received" and reappears each restart

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sms, lenovo

Several months ago I received a spam message on my Android phone (nothing unusual there).
What **is** unusual, is the fact that this SMS is now stuck somewhere inside my phone's messaging module and it keeps "receiving" every time I turn the phone on (including after restart).

I have contacted my SP, and they are not related to this issue. In fact, I tried different SIM, and this SMS is received again for entirely different SIM.

What I'm inferring from this is that text is stuck somewhere on my device marked as "new SMS" forever, and each time phone turns on, it looks into that list, finds it and displays it, but somehow fails to take "new SMS" flag away from it.

The question the is:
Is there a queue(or a file) where I can find that stuck message and delete it manually?

Rolling back to factory defaults do not seem like a good option to solve my problem at this time.

If this matters, my SMS app also always displays "you have 2 new SMS" badge (strange that it displays 2, but it does).

**Phone details**:
Lenovo S660 with latest available for it official Android 4.4 firmware. Unrooted (rooting is possible).

Comment: Did you try clearing data and cache of the SMS app? This should solve the issue. Otherwise  it  might be a malware or somethings.

Comment: Are you using the stock messaging app?  Try a third-party app like Google Messenger, EvolveSMS, Textra, or many others, and see if those show the message(s) so they can potentially be received/deleted.

Comment: @RMarkwald, I use stock Lenovo app. However, I did try google one, and I seem to recall it being present there as well. But it was quite a while ago, so I don't remember exactly. I'll try again and update the quesion with details.

Comment: @esQmo, wouldn't that clear all my SMS in the process? I was hoping there'd be a more targeted solution.

Comment: Ofcourse it will, all those are not on the SIM card

Comment: @esQmo OK then. I'll hold off on that for the time being. In the meantime, can you help me work out the possible cause of what's happening?

Comment: @M. Prokhorov I really have no idea  of what  can be causing this. May be something with the cache memory.  By the way, you should  try clearing the  cache from the recovery  menu. (No data loss of course )

Comment: Power the phone  holding  volume up button then select  recovery.